inject() Angular making it difficult
How could I be using the inject() functionality in Angular 15 for this case?

Way using constructor():

      import { datadogRum } from '@datadog/browser-rum';

      constructor(...) {
          datadogRum.init({
              applicationId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
              clientToken: 'EX-app',
              ...
          });
      }


Way using inject():

          import { datadogRum } from '@datadog/browser-rum';

          private datadogRum_ = inject(datadogRum.init);

          ngOnInit() {
                 datadogRum_({
                        applicationId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                        clientToken: 'EX-app',
                        ...
                  });
          }

Where using inject() causes the following error:
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[function () { -> function () { -> function () {]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for function () {!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:7493:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:12084:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3201:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3246:12)
    at ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10041:12)
    at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:622:60)
    at inject (core.mjs:705:12)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you please add code of datadogRum class? From the error it looks like there is no provider defined in component for the service you are using. Either don't use init of the class or the datadogRum is not a service at all.

Just don't use it. Never. There is no need for a dependency injection mechanism. Never.

As you can read in the docs, you can use Angular's dependency injection mechanism only with classes that use Angular decorators, such as @Injectable(), @Component(), @Directive, ... You are trying to inject a function which has no Angular decorator. Angular's DI is not designed to handle those and throws an error, which is totally expected.
To answer you question: You can't use inject() in this case.

Thank you very much, it is very clear to me now.

First of all you have to have a service/injectionToken to inject it into angular injectionContext. If you have @Injectable() like a person before said it would work.
Second of all I would have used APP_INITIALIZER like this for setting up a configuration before app starts
